# Hive load data action using oozie

Tags: hadoop, load, hive, oozie

I defined a hive action in oozie workflow.xml, performs data load from hdfs path. But, fortunately it is not working.The same script working for creating the file in hive. Could you guys please refer my workflow.xml,job.properties,script files and correct me if any mistakes i did. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.
    script.hql contains the "load data inpath '/../hdfs dir' into table test;"

```
**workflow.xml**


<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="hive-wf">
    <start to="hive-action"/>

     <action name="hive-action">
              <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
              <job-tracker>${jobtracker}</job-tracker>
              <name-node>${namenode}</name-node>
              <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
                  <configuration>

                       <property>
                             <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                             <value>${queueName}</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                              <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                              <value>${namenode}/</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                             <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
                              <value>2</value>
                        </property>
                  </configuration>
              <script>script.hql</script>
              </hive>
              <ok to="end"/>
              <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
         <message>Hive failed with some error.please look into that[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>



job.properties
--------------

namenode=hdfs://namenodeipaddress:8020    
jobtracker=jobtrackeripaddress:8032    
queueName=default    
oozie.use.system.libpath=true    
oozie.libpath=${namenode}/user/oozie/share/lib    
oozie.wf.application.path=${namenode}/user/username/OozieScripts
```

Please find the below error log from oozie.

```
2014-11-24 11:07:43,984 INFO org.apache.oozie.servlet.CallbackServlet: SERVER[HOSTNAME] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@hive-action] callback for action [0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@hive-action]
2014-11-24 11:07:44,339 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionEndXCommand: SERVER[HOSTNAME] USER[USERNAME] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@hive-action] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2014-11-24 11:07:44,391 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[HOSTNAME] USER[USERNAME] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@fail] Start action [0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@fail] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2014-11-24 11:07:44,391 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[HOSTNAME] USER[USERNAME] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@fail] [***0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@fail***]Action status=DONE
2014-11-24 11:07:44,391 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[HOSTNAME] USER[USERNAME] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@fail] [***0000005-141121151044934-oozie-oozi-W@fail***]Action updated in DB!
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you provide logs?

Comment: Can you provied error logs?

Comment: Please find the above error code that was logged. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a hive-default.xml file to execute the hive scripts in oozie and that file has be mentioned in the workflow.xml as

```
<property>
                         <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                         <value>${queueName}</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                          <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                          ***<value>/usr/foo/hive-0.6-default.xml</value>***
                    </property>
                    <property>
                         <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
                          <value>2</value>
                    </property>
```

For more info refer, [Hive workflow model](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_HiveActionExtension.html)